# How to setup ansible for ec2 instance?

Tags: ansible

I have launched an ec2 instance with ubuntu system. I am going to install `git` on that system through ansible. Below is my playbook file:

```
---

- hosts: ec2
  roles:
    - git
```

below is my git role task file:

```
---
- name: install git
  sudo: yes
  yum:
    pkg: git
    state: latest
```

I get below error when I run `ansible-playbook -i hosts git.yml`:

```
TASK [git : install git] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [xxxxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "python2 bindings for rpm are needed for this module. python2 yum module is needed fo
r this  module"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/Users/joey/dev/dbkoda/jenkins-docker-file/playbooks/git.retry
```

I am not sure why I get this error message. I have installed python on the ec2 instance. And `python2` is available on PATH.

Below is Ansible version I am using:

```
$ ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.3.1.0
  config file =
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
  python version = 2.7.13 (default, Jul 18 2017, 09:17:00) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Yum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yum_(.rpm)) is a standard package manager on Red Hat family distributions.

Ubuntu, based on Debian, uses [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(Debian)).

In Ansible use the [`apt` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/apt_module.html).

You can also try the [`package` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/package_module.html), but since package names differ across package managers, you might not be able to create a common play for different distributions.